# Disable multiselect in Dropzone file upload control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone control, i want to achieve if file dialog box is opened, it should not upload more than one file at a time, it can allow multiselect but i want to restrict multi-selection in file upload box.
I have explored dropzone website and related questions but none of them works actually.
I have set

```
 uploadMultiple:false; 
 queueLimit:1;
```

but it is still allowing to do multiselection.

The reason of disabling multiselection is, if i allow it it gives me wrong no of files in Request.Files array.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
maxFiles: 1 
This will prevent the user form selecting multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the 'multiple' from your Input element should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiple={false}`:

```
useDropzone({ multiple: false, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/png' });
```